# Webpack dev server slow initial load

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example and everything works great except for the Webpack dev server.

For some reason, the initial load of the 6MB "main-***.js" can take up to 2 minutes due to a very slow transfer. Other times it's <5 seconds.

To be clear, this is after the compilation, and CPU usage is at ~0%, it is solely serving the file to the browser that is slow. I don't see this behavior with HMR or serving any other files from this machine.

Any theories? Are there any likely settings I can experiment with or debug options?

Comment: are you requiring tons of modules? I wonder if it has anything to do with web sockets? If I remember, that's how it accomplishes hot reloads? Could be wrong about that

Comment: I'm basically just requiring the default listed here: https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/package.json

It definitely feels like something's weird with the connection, since 50% of the time it loads in <5 seconds, and the other 50% it takes a random amount of time between 30 seconds and ~3 minutes. Wish I could narrow it down further but it's an enigma to me...

Comment: I was having similar issue and have tweaked different sourcemap option but a new port somehow solved it for me. Wondering if something else is taking up the current port.